# Android SRP Client working with Linux Server through OpenSSL SRP

Tags: java, android, linux, openssl

I am trying to develop an Android client which connects to a Linux server securely through SRP protocol from [RFC 2945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2945) . I know that the Server implements the SRP protocol through OpenSSL library APIs but in the Android client I have used 
[srpforjava on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/srpforjava/) for SRP implementation. (Reason: This implementation has both the server & client code so I can easily test my code).

Now the big question is whether my Android client work straight away with the server which is using OpenSSL SRP library APIs? If thats not guaranteed then do I need to build OpenSSL source code for Android (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) in order to use OpenSSL SRP APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the big question is whether my [RFC 2945] Android client work straight away with the server which is using OpenSSL SRP library APIs?

No. OpenSSL uses SRP-6 from [RFC 5054](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5054.txt). SRP-6 stops a couple of attacks present in SRP-3, like the 2-for-1 guessing attack. The v6 fixes are incompatible with v3.

Also see the OpenSSL CHANGE LOG under the heading [Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012]](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#x26):

> *) Make TLS-SRP code conformant with RFC 5054 API cleanup
>       (removal of unnecessary code)
>       [Peter Sylvester <peter.sylvester@edelweb.fr>]

Comment: Thank you, so I will have to build the OpenSSL source for Android and start using the OpenSSL APIs. Any idea if the BoringSSL (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#boringSSL) have the SRP protocol implementation built-in?